# React App uncaught Type Error: Class constructor App cannot be invoked without 'new'

Tags: reactjs

Is there any error in this ReactJS App code?
But VS code doesn't highlight the error.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
export default class App extends Component{
    render(){
        return(
        <div>
        <h1>Hello, world! App JS</h1>
        <h2>It is {new Date().toLocaleTimeString()}</h2>
        </div>
        );
    }
}
setInterval(App, 1000);
```

Comment: `App` -> `<App/>` Also, where is `ReactDOM.render` ?

Comment: Index.js file =>         `import React, { Fragment } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './components/App';
import './index.css';

ReactDOM.render(
    <Fragment>
        <App/>
        <App/>
    </Fragment>
  ,document.getElementById('root'));`

Answer (score 1):

That `setInterval` is the cause. You're trying to invoke `App` constructor without the `new` keyword which behind the scenes React is doing for you.

Instead of trying to invoke it like this, introduce a state (which stores this time) inside the `App` class which you update after each interval and that will re-render the `App` JSX again with your updated time.

Also I am assuming that you are importing the `App` class somewhere and using it like `<App/>`.